# Repairing a North Face Tent rain cover

Tags: tents, maintenance, rain-gear

I have bought a [North Face RoadRunner 3 tent](https://www.google.com/search?q=north%20faceroad%20runner%203#hl=en&tbo=d&spell=1&q=north%20face%20roadrunner%203&sa=X&ei=nWnZUPTIN6TL0AXxrYGQCg&ved=0CDQQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=b3563551dbd44492&bpcl=40096503&biw=1366&bih=643) 10 years ago. It is a great tent, and it served me well during a 9-month trip to South America.

[image]

The problem is that the transparent part of the rain cover - the so-called "window" - has disintegrated, and now there is a nice hole instead of a window:

[image]

[image]

Other than that, the tent is perfect.

How do I patch the missing part? I don't it to be transparent, just water-proof.

Comment: I'm assuming this is all in prep for your NZ trip.  You'll give a trip report afterwards, I hope.  I'd like to hear all about it.

Answer (score 6):

If you're going for sealing, just stitch some silnylon over it with a sewing machine and seam seal it.  I would recommend sewing two rows as they did, one in the middle of their two, and one an equal distance to the outside of the two existing.  The first of the two should provide strong support due to the layering.

Make sure you use some fabric on the back side as well to help prevent tearing along the new seam.